# Brackets in zsh on MacOS

Tags: shell, git, zsh

I'm updating my shell to zsh on Mojave. It's gone swimmingly so far except for when I'm in git repos, and I get these weird color bracket things. I don't know where to report the error or nearly what to do in order to debug. I'm assuming it's trying to change colors. I'm running zsh version 5.7.1 installed via Homebrew. I was having this issue with the stock version as well.

[image: Zsh color brackets]

Comment: It goes away when I disable the zsh-bash plugin. Can I just go without it?

Comment: It's look like the default theme in oh-my-zsh. Try to change the prompt text or .zshrc file.